# Autosys File watcher setup

Tags: autosys

I have file watcher which will be getting terminated as set by term_run_time. But the waiting job (waiting for file watcher to success) still be in activated state, I need to terminate waiting jobs also.

Text_Box
  Job_A
  File_watcher_A

As defined above box name is Text_Box , job is Job_A, File watcher is file watcher. Job_A has condition Job_A -> Condition (Success(File_watcher_A))

Once file_Watcher_A terminated Job_A also should terminate, can you please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set the box_terminator attribute in your File Watcher job definition to true. This will terminate the box when the File Watcher terminates.

Next, set the job_terminator attribute in Job_A to true. This will terminate Job_A when the box terminates.